# Keeping query mobile headers the same

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am writing a little app that has the same header across multiple pages, so rather than write the same bit of code time and again, I wanted to include a variable, similar to 'include('header.php')' in php.

I have currently done:

```
  //Set header for each page
  var fund_header = '<div data-role="header" data-theme="z" data-position="inline"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript: reset(); $.mobile.changePage("#fund_1");" data-icon="delete" class="restart">Restart</a><h1>Funding</h1><a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right" data-iconpos="notext" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Home</a></div>';
```

Then on the pages added:

```
<div data-role="page" id="fund_2" data-theme="z">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(fund_header);</script>
```

Is this the best practice? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the header in a variable, you may want to make a separate header html file and load it using Ajax.

I haven't tried it myself, but looking at jQuery Mobile's API, it appears you could use `$.mobile.loadPage` for this, rather than writing the ajax request yourself.

The request would probably look something like:
`$.mobile.loadPage( 'header.html', { pageContainer: $('header') });`

See: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/api/methods.html

If that didn't work, you could also use jQuery's `.ajax` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Would love to hear if there is a better solution provided by JQM though.